# admin inlines over one2one field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have three django models and I want to edit item's instances on order's page. Is it possible?

```
#models.py

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart')

class Cart(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    cart = models.OneToOneField('Cart')

#admin.py

ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

CartInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Cart

Order(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CartInline,) # I need ItemInline here...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it so Order is an inline of Cart, rather than the other way around?